# Can't authenticate to Adobe Analytics API Integration

Tags: adobe-analytics

I have created an integration for Adobe Analytics API at https://console.adobe.io with 0auth athentication method. According to the documentation (https://github.com/AdobeDocs/analytics-2.0-apis/blob/master/oauth-curl.md), first I have to make a request to this url:

https://ims-na1.adobelogin.com/ims/authorize?client_id={CLIENT ID}&redirect_uri={REDIRECT URI}&scope=openid,AdobeID,read_organizations,additional_info.job_function,additional_info.projectedProductContext&response_type=code

and then ask this url:

https://ims-na1.adobelogin.com/ims/token/v1

for a token passing this parameters as the request's data:

grant_type=authorization_code&client_id={CLIENT ID}&client_secret={CLIENT SECRET}&code={AUTH CODE QUERY PARAMETER}

The problem is that when I make a POST to the first url it redirects me to adobe login and then (after the login), it redirects me to the page that has the code.

Is there a way to make this login from a script that makes the API calls?

Apart of that, I noticed that the Client secret is the same during some time and then it changes. Is there a way to get the client secret in an automatic way?

Comment: If you want to handle api authentication server-side / without user interaction, instead of OAuth Integration, you should use the Service Account Integration.

Comment: I tried that way and it worked. Thank you!

Comment: @CrayonViolent Maybe your comment should/could be an answer?